# How to change rails default "destroy" action in javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to change the default functionality Rails uses for the destroy action by adding ajax and an animation to remove the item. I know how to implement the javascript, but I'm not sure what is the best way to "tap in" or override this bit of javascript, especially now that the jquery_ujs file is vendored away somewhere due to the asset pipeline. What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: Easiest way to proceed is not using `remote` in the link and code your js on the raw html.

Comment: I'm not using `remote`, just the default behavior which displays an alert and submits as a synchronous request.

Comment: Just write a simple link and add the DELETE method in your js.

Comment: In other words, skip the rails ujs by not adding the data attributes and writing the JavaScript I want to use instead?

Comment: Right, so you'll be sure there is no interference with Rails' js. And it will be easy to add your own js to all delete links.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks! If this were an answer, I would have accepted it. =]

Answer (score 0):

You can still add ajax and animation without bothering about the rails default behavior or the ujs behavior.

In the destroy action, you just have to respond to a javascript request and create the necessary js file that does the animation magic using jquery.

```
def destroy
  # perform destructive action (optional)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Make sure there's a file called `destroy.js.erb` in the `views/<controller_name>/` folder.

Comment: this way, the OP must do with the alert box, which is, perhaps, not what he wants.

Comment: hmm...putting javascript in a view script doesn't seem like the best approach.